# GroupBy complex query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I've created a viewmodel for the stats page as follows:

```
public class StatsSeasonViewModel
{
    public int player_id { get; set; }
    public string player_name { get; set; }
    public int games_played { get; set; }
    public int total_first { get; set; }
    public int total_second { get; set; }
    public int total_third { get; set; }
    public int total_wickets { get; set; }
    public double avg_wickets { get; set; }
    public int total_points { get; set; }
    public double avg_points { get; set; }
}
```

I have a complex LINQ statement to populate the model. I feel this could be simpler, but I don't know how to do it:

```
const int first_place = 5;
const int second_place = 3;
const int third_place = 1;

var model =
from s in _db.Stats
join p in _db.Players
on s.player_id equals p.player_id
where s.season_id == current_season
select new StatsSeasonViewModel
{
    player_id = p.player_id,
    player_name = p.name,
    games_played = (from st1 in _db.Stats
                    where st1.player_id == s.player_id
                    select st1).Count(),
    total_first = (from st2 in _db.Stats
                    where st2.player_id == s.player_id && st2.place == 1
                    select st2).Count(),
    total_second = (from st3 in _db.Stats
                    where st3.player_id == s.player_id && st3.place == 2
                    select st3).Count(),
    total_third = (from st4 in _db.Stats
                    where st4.player_id == s.player_id && st4.place == 3
                    select st4).Count(),
    total_wickets = (from st5 in _db.Stats
                        where st5.player_id == s.player_id
                        select st5.wickets).Sum(),
    avg_wickets = (from st5 in _db.Stats
                    where st5.player_id == s.player_id
                    select st5.wickets).Sum() /
                    (from st1 in _db.Stats
                    where st1.player_id == s.player_id
                    select st1).Count(),
    total_points = (from st5 in _db.Stats
                    where st5.player_id == s.player_id
                    select st5.wickets).Sum() +
                    (
                        (from st2 in _db.Stats
                            where st2.player_id == s.player_id && st2.place == 1
                            select st2).Count()
                    ) * first_place +
                    (
                        (from st3 in _db.Stats
                            where st3.player_id == s.player_id && st3.place == 2
                            select st3).Count()
                    ) * second_place +
                    (
                        (from st4 in _db.Stats
                            where st4.player_id == s.player_id && st4.place == 3
                            select st4).Count()
                    ) * third_place,
    avg_points = (
                    (from st5 in _db.Stats
                        where st5.player_id == s.player_id
                        select st5.wickets).Sum() +
                    (
                        (from st2 in _db.Stats
                            where st2.player_id == s.player_id && st2.place == 1
                            select st2).Count()
                    ) * first_place +
                    (
                        (from st3 in _db.Stats
                            where st3.player_id == s.player_id && st3.place == 2
                            select st3).Count()
                    ) * second_place +
                    (
                        (from st4 in _db.Stats
                            where st4.player_id == s.player_id && st4.place == 3
                            select st4).Count()
                    ) * third_place
                ) /
                (from st1 in _db.Stats
                    where st1.player_id == s.player_id
                    select st1).Count()
};
```

So the biggest issue I have now is that I need to do a group by on this query so that it won't display duplicates. But when I try to add the group by, then I get lost on how to do the rest of the query after the SELECT. How can I do a group by on the above query and get the results I need?

EDIT: FWIW here is the results I am getting: http://ecl.moyl.com/Home/Stats

The second issue is of course the complexity of the query itself. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Create an Enumerable range from 1 - 3 then just filter like this
.Where(st => range.Contains(st.place) && st.player_id = s.player_id) then you need to group by place.  But It might just make more sense to have all of this in a view in your DB instead so you can just grab from there.  But you get an Upvote for the effort you put in

Comment: Ha! Thanks for the upvote! I want to group by player_id, not place. Right now what is happening is I am getting duplicate entries for all the players. I tried adding group s by s.player_id into statGroup but then all that complex stuff in the select statement bombs out when I try to build the model. You may be right about creating a view in the database - oddly enough I've never tried that before!

Comment: you might find the view more useful, because if everything is index properly, you won't have to do as much work pulling out that query.  And you can pull that view into entity framework

Comment: @xgrinderx, I've updated my answer on how to handle the grouping and populate your view model.  A minor change to your object will make it possible.  NOTE: if you get a run time error complaining about multiple iterations on your group, then just do a `.ToList()` and perform your Linq over that list.

Comment: Solved this using a View. which made this MUCH simpler. Unfortunately I still don't know how to do grouping within a LINQ statement, but using views I may not have to. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a couple ways to simplify things, however to answer your main question:

```
var search = from st2 in _db.Stats
    where st2.player_id = s.player_id
    group st2 by st2.player_id
```

You would iterate over each group to get the `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` to get the individual counts ([ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384063.aspx)).

```
for (var playerGroup in search)
{
     Console.WriteFormat("{0}: {1}\n", playerGroup.Key, playerGroup.Count());
}
```

Your code could be a bit more readable if you used a slightly different way of writing your counts/sums.

Example, this:

```
games_played = (from st1 in _db.Stats
                where st1.player_id == s.player_id
                select st1).Count(),
total_wickets = (from st5 in _db.Stats
                    where st5.player_id == s.player_id
                    select st5.wickets).Sum()
```

could become this:

```
var filter = st => st.player_id == s.player_id; // reuse this over and over

games_played = _db.Stats.Where(filter).Count(),
total_wickets = _db.Stats.Where(filter).Sum(st5 => st5.wickets)
```

---

In fact, to "have your cake and eat it too", the whole filter becomes unnecessary when you use the group by statement.  You have to change how you create your model so you can pass in your `IGrouping<int,Stat>` (assuming that's what the types are) to the constructor.  In this approach your overall query looks like this:

```
const int first_place = 5;
const int second_place = 3;
const int third_place = 1;

var model =
    from s in _db.Stats
    join p in _db.Players
    on s.player_id equals p.player_id
    where s.season_id == current_season
    group st by st.player_id into group
    select new StatsSeasonViewModel(group)
```

Now your `StatsSeasonViewModel` is responsible for populating its stats based on the values in the group

```
 public StatsSeasonViewModel(IGrouping<int,Stat> playerStats)
 {
     player_id = playerStats.Key;
     games_played = playerStats.Count();
     total_wickets = playerStats.Sum(st=>st.wickets);
     // ....
 }
```

Comment: you can simplify filtering some of the stats by saying where place <= 3

Comment: @johnny5, it would simplify the code by making it shorter, but not easier to read, I think Berin is in the spot here

Comment: Berin this is awesome. I am total noob at this coming from classic ASP background trying to learn c#, MVC, and LINQ with this little app. I originally had that in the question itself but I guess it got moderated out as unnecessary. I ended up using a View as suggested by johnny 5 above, but I think your answer has at least pointed me in the right direction for learning how to use grouping as I move forward in learning. THANKS!

Comment: Remember to mark his answer as it helps others to find The answer

Answer (score 1):

You are using an outdated way of writing Linq in MVC. Use the dbContext to easily find the player by creating a method that takes a player Id as a variable and use Distinct to return distinct values and avoid duplicates:

```
var player = _db.Players.Where(p => p.player_id == Id);
```

Then handle the attributes by lambda-joining the player with the stats table:

```
var st1 in _db.Stats.Where(st1 => st1.player_id == player.player_id).Distinct().Count();
```

EDIT:

I Changed it a bit, because you would want the distinct in the second expression, since the first already would find a distinct value